# How display a list of data order by date?

Tags: flutter

Here is the result now :

[image]

It is much better but i Don't know why BELSHINA BOBRUISK is not centered vertically. As you can see the others team are centered vertically. FC SMOELVITCHI is centered. Strange. Too i would like display the "2020-06-01" in mobile format so if it is french mobile it will be "01-06-2020".
And another question i Don't know why my mobile app use the theme with fontfamily but not all. I have some pages with a part of data in good family font and the other part in default font, its is really strange

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_app/menu_member.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:flutter_app/appbar_draw.dart';

// Create a Form widget.
class Affiche_Matchs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  _Affiche_Matchs_State createState() {
    return _Affiche_Matchs_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class _Affiche_Matchs_State extends State<Affiche_Matchs> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> radioValues = [];
  Future<List<Match>> grid;

  Future <List<Match>> Liste_Match_Display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/display_matchs.php';

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.get(url,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Match> Matchs = [];
    var i=0;
    for (var u in jsondata) {
      i=i+1;
      Match match = Match(u["id"],u["equipe1"],u["equipe2"],u["type_prono"],u["date_debut"],u["heure_debut"]);
      Matchs.add(match);
      radioValues.add("");
    }
    return Matchs;
  }

  void initState() {
    grid = Liste_Match_Display();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: drawappbar(true),
        drawer: new DrawerOnly(className: Affiche_Matchs()),
        body:
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child:
          FutureBuilder(
            future: grid,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          default:
          if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return new Center(child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
          }
          else {
          List<Match> values = snapshot.data;
          Match lastitem;
          lastitem=values[0];
          if (values.isEmpty) {
          return Container(
          child: Center(
          child: Text("Aucun match disponible !!!")
          )
          );
          }
          else {
            return Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: ListView.builder(itemCount: values.length,itemBuilder: (_,index) {
                          bool header = lastitem.date_debut !=
                              values[index].date_debut;
                          lastitem = values[index];
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              (header || index == 0)
                                  ?
                          Container(
                            height: 30,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.blue[700],
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                color: Colors.blue[700]
                            ),
                            child : new Text(values[index].date_debut,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.white),),
                          )// here display header
                                  :
                                  Container(),
                                  Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20,bottom:20),
                                  child: Center(
                                  child: Text(values[index].heure_debut),
                                  ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                              Text(values[index].equipe1,style: TextStyle(fontSize:12)),
                              draw_grid("1", index, values[index].typeprono),
                              draw_grid("N", index, values[index].typeprono), //
                              draw_grid("2", index, values[index].typeprono), //
                              Text(values[index].equipe2,style: TextStyle(fontSize:12)),
                            ]
                  ),
                  ]
                          );
                        }
                )
            );
          }
          };
          };
          }
                          ),
                ),
            );
        }

  draw_grid (String choix, int index,String type_prono) {
    if (type_prono.contains(choix)) {
      return new InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (radioValues[index] == choix) {
              radioValues[index] = "";
            }
            else {
              radioValues[index] = choix;
            }
          });
          print(radioValues);
        },
        child:
        Container(
          height: 30.0,
          width: 30.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2,left: 2),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(choix,
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color:
                    radioValues[index] == choix ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                    //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: radioValues[index] == choix
                ? Colors.red
                : Colors.white,
            border: new Border.all(
                width: 2.0,
                color: radioValues[index] == choix
                    ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.red),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(5)),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    else {
      return Text("");
    }
  }

}

class Match {

  final String id;
  final String equipe1;
  final String equipe2;
  final String typeprono;
  final String date_debut;
  final String heure_debut;

  const Match(this.id,this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeprono,this.date_debut,this.heure_debut);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort you list base on date and then you can display by checking you have to display header or not.

Following code help you to understand more and then you can implement.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> radioValues = [];
  Future<List<Match>> grid;

  Future<List<Match>> Liste_Match_Display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/display_matchs.php';

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization':
          'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOjE1ODg5NTQ0NDgsImlhdCI6MTU4ODk1NDQ0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MDE0NDQ4LCJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoiMSIsImVtYWlsIjoicGFzMzBAbmV0Y291cnJpZXIuY29tIn19.-jcyoxtkNVWWagune6EOjInjBgObyxf9gweXJrA2MxLL5fRTW1pkFSFrJOW8uYzhVpaZ4CF9A-c_m8akUq74NA '
    });

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Match> Matchs = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var u in jsondata) {
      i = i + 1;
      Match match = Match(u["id"], u["equipe1"], u["equipe2"], u["type_prono"],
          u["date_debut"], u["heure_debut"]);
      Matchs.add(match);
      radioValues.add("");
    }
    return Matchs;
  }

  void initState() {
    grid = Liste_Match_Display();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //  appBar: drawappbar(true),
      //drawer: new DrawerOnly(className: Affiche_Matchs()),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: grid,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return new Center(
                      child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                    );
                  } else {
                    List<Match> values = snapshot.data;
                    Match lastitem;
                    lastitem = values[0];
                    if (values.isEmpty) {
                      return Container(
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text("Aucun match disponible !!!")));
                    } else {
                      return Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: values.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                bool header = lastitem.date_debut !=
                                    values[index].date_debut;
                                lastitem = values[index];
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    (header || index == 0)
                                        ? Container(
                                            height: 30,
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                .size
                                                .width,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.blue[700],
                                                  width: 2,
                                                ),
                                                color: Colors.blue[700]),
                                            child: new Text(
                                              values[index].date_debut,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ) // here display header
                                        : Container(),
                                    Text(values[index].heure_debut),
                                    Text(values[index].equipe1),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        draw_grid("1", index,
                                            values[index].typeprono),
                                        draw_grid("N", index,
                                            values[index].typeprono), //
                                        draw_grid("2", index,
                                            values[index].typeprono), //
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Text(values[index].equipe2),
// here display whole item
                                  ],
                                );
                              }));
                    }
                  }
                  ;
              }
              ;
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  draw_grid(String choix, int index, String type_prono) {
    if (type_prono.contains(choix)) {
      return new InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (radioValues[index] == choix) {
              radioValues[index] = "";
            } else {
              radioValues[index] = choix;
            }
          });
          print(radioValues);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(choix,
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color:
                        radioValues[index] == choix ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                    //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: radioValues[index] == choix ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
            border: new Border.all(
                width: 2.0,
                color: radioValues[index] == choix ? Colors.red : Colors.red),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(5)),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text("");
    }
  }
}

class Match {
  final String id;
  final String equipe1;
  final String equipe2;
  final String typeprono;
  final String date_debut;
  final String heure_debut;

  const Match(this.id, this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeprono,
      this.date_debut, this.heure_debut);
}
```

Comment: for the moment i use datatable but you are ok i Don't need it for display the list of game ???

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain again?

Comment: i have updated the orgin post with my code based on your solution but as you can see there is little problems, can you help me ?

Comment: can you share global token, because without that i am unable to check.

Comment: 'authorization': globals.token ??

Comment: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOjE1ODg5NTQ0NDgsImlhdCI6MTU4ODk1NDQ0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MDE0NDQ4LCJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoiMSIsImVtYWlsIjoicGFzMzBAbmV0Y291cnJpZXIuY29tIn19.-jcyoxtkNVWWagune6EOjInjBgObyxf9gweXJrA2MxLL5fRTW1pkFSFrJOW8uYzhVpaZ4CF9A-c_m8akUq74NA

Comment: @axis-medias playwith row textbase line it will work for you. now your api is not working correctly for me. accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Croasaxisalignment property value set center will work.@axis-medias

Comment: it is good now :) The text was not aligned correctly because there was line return in MySQL so now it is good. perhaps i need to delete spaces for all text coming from mysql